# Python - Kill Spawned Popen Chilld process using SIGTERM

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, sigterm

I have an python module called `app.py` which has the following code

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":    
    for _ in range(settings.DJANGO_RQ_WORKERS):
        # spawn up non-blocking rq worker
        subprocess.Popen(
            [
                sys.executable,
                "manage.py",
                "rqworker"
            ],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        )
    # spawn up non-blocking rq scheduler
    subprocess.Popen(
        [
            sys.executable,
            "manage.py",
            "rqscheduler"
        ],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    )
    subprocess.check_call(
        [
            "gunicorn",
            "--bind",
            args.bind_address,
            "chilli.wsgi:application",
            "--workers",
            '2',
            "--threads",
            "2",
        ],
        env=dict(os.environ),
        cwd=os.getcwd(),
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    )
```

I am running file as `python app.py` and `ps -ef | grep python` yields

```bash
503 96626 37650   0  4:21pm ttys006    0:00.80 python application.py
503 96629 96626   0  4:21pm ttys006    0:00.91 python manage.py rqworker
503 96630 96626   0  4:21pm ttys006    0:00.90 python manage.py rqscheduler
503 96631 96626   0  4:21pm ttys006    0:00.22 python gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 chilli.wsgi:application --workers 2 --threads 2
503 96632 96631   0  4:21pm ttys006    0:00.62 python gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 chilli.wsgi:application --workers 2 --threads 2
503 96633 96631   0  4:21pm ttys006    0:00.61 python gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 chilli.wsgi:application --workers 2 --threads 2
```

but when I send `kill -15 96626` (pid of application.py) only this process terminate and the rest of the process run in background. How do I kill all the subprocess spawned when I send SIGTERM to my main module?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a signal to all process group, you need to use `pgid()` value with "-" prefix. In your case, it would be `kill -15 -96626`

Comment: It does not work

Comment: Maybe this processes ignore the TERM signal or handling it , can you try another terminate signal like SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2, SIGHUP ?

Comment: Nope. Can you please considering upvoting the question?

Comment: I tried vote up, did you try to run your subprocess (for example gunicorn proc.) from fresh terminal and send TERM signal to that process from another terminal ? Is it terminated ?

Comment: I experienced a similar issue. Here is something which helped me: https://alexandra-zaharia.github.io/posts/kill-subprocess-and-its-children-on-timeout-python/.